# What does 'Dem' mean in this context?

Tags: pronoun, dative, definite-article

Can someone clearly explain the use of "dem" in the following contexts?

> Dem halten betroffene Eltern und Pädagogen jedoch entgegen, dass ...
>
> [...] und natürlich auch aus der hohen Anzahl von Spielern sowie dem
>   ungeheuren Zeitaufwand sieht man, ...
>
> Dem kann ich nur zustimmen, dem anderen Argument hingegen muss ich
>   widersprechen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 1st and 3rd sentence, *dem* is the **demonstrative pronoun** *das* (or, much less likely but undistinguishable without more context: *der*) in dative case. It looks like it is referring to something that has been mentioned before. [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Demonstr.html?lang=en) has a short explanation on how this works. The pronoun is declined into dative case because it is referring to something that plays the role of an object that has to be in dative simply because the verbs in these sentences (*entgegenhalten* and *zustimmen*, resp.) require it.

In the 2nd sentence, *dem* is the **article** *der*, again in dative case. The preposition *aus* always requires the dative case, so both "die hohe Anzahl von Spielern" and "der ungeheure Zeitaufwand" need to be set in dative case.

Comment: Nicht dass es einen Unterschied machte, aber ist es nicht eher *das* als *der*?

Comment: @CarstenS Dank an Dich, den hilfreichen Hinweisgeber, _dem_ ich weitgehend zustimme, _dem_ ich aber auch entgegenhalte möchte, dass _der_ nicht völlig augeschlossen ist.

Answer (score 0):

Alle drei sind Dative!

- **1** + **3** sind *Dativ-Objekte* - (***wem*** entgegenhalten/zustimmen)
- **2** wäre ein *Präpositional-Objekt* - (aus ***wem*** sehen)

Der zweite Satz ist aber unakzeptabel...

Man sieht ***AN*** der Zahl der Spieler... - oder
Man ersieht ***AUS*** der Zahl der Spieler...

Comment: "Unakzeptabel" ist ein hartes Wort für eine kleine Ungenauigkeit im Ausdruck, wie sie alle Tage vorkommt.

Comment: @Matthias: Dreh den Satz mal um : 'Man sieht aus dem ungeheuren Zeitaufwand... -> klingt nicht wirklich deutsch... ;-) Kommt in meinem alltäglichen Umfeld jedenfalls ***nie*** vor...

Comment: Also wenn überhaupt klingt es nicht wie _heutiges_ Deutsch. "Man sieht aus dem bisherigen leicht: daß der Begriff eines absolut notwendigen Wesens ein reiner Vernunftbegriff, d. i. eine bloße Idee sei..." - so hat [Kant](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/kritik-der-reinen-vernunft-1-auflage-3508/102) geschrieben.

Comment: @Matthias: Er schreibt aber auch in eben demselben Werk -> ‘Daß aber überall nur der letztere stattfinden könne, ***ersieht*** man ***daraus***. - Ebenso verwendet er fast durchgehend 'sehen' im eindeutigen Sinn von 'schauen' -> 'Das erste Argument sieht nur auf die absolute Totalität der Reihe der Bedingungen...' - Kant ist Philosoph und bedient sich einer sehr kunstvollen Sprache. Ein '*hartes*' Beispiel um den heutigen Sprachgebrauch zu rechtfertigen ;-) Aber super-schön, zugegeben...

Comment: Seit wann sagt man denn „unakzeptabel“?

Comment: @CarstenS Das musst Du den [Duden fragen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unakzeptabel). Mir kam es aber auch komisch vor.